# Error: The received token is of incorrect token type -- What should the token look like?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I recently registered to Microsoft Azure and set up a Cognitive Services Account. Using the instructions from the [Text Translation API Documentation](http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html) I was able to retrieve an authentication token from the */issueToken* service using the [interactive online example](http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/oauth-token.html). However, if I want to use that token (for example for the [interactive /translate example](http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html#!/default/get_Translate)) I end up with the response

```
<html><body><h1>Argument Exception</h1><p>Method: Translate()</p><p>Parameter: </p><p>Message: The received token is of incorrect token type.</p><code></code><p>message id=0344.V2_Rest.Translate.3D8A6FF1</p></body></html>
```

What am I doing wrong? What should the token look like and in what format should I supply it? In the online example I specified the token by setting the *appid* field to "Bearer *[token]*" where *[token]* is the response from */issueToken*.

In my case the token is a 687 characters long string which can be separated into three parts (using '.' as delimiter). The first two parts are base64-encoded and just contain some JSON-encoded information that stays constant (except the expiration date field). The third and last part changes everytime and can not be decoded using base64. Instead of supplying the full token I also tried to just use various substrings of the full token but without any success so far.

I also tried authenticating via curl using the *Authentication*-header instead of the *appid*-field, which also did not work for me.

Comment: Are you working on C#?

Comment: Yes, I want to use C# for the actual project. But since the Azure-authentication can be done with anything that supports GET and POST requests I would be happy to get it to work in any language.

Answer (score 3):

The token actually has to look like it is described in the question text (at least as of now). The problem in my case was that I used the wrong subscription key. Note here: You get a different key for the translation API and the speech API each; even though both run under Cognitive Services and even if you connect both through the same resources.

I post this as an answer to my question because I want to confirm that all the steps listed above are correct and because I hope that it may help people who do the same mistake as I did.